# How do I make a BigQuery data transfer "On Demand" with the command line?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, command-line, google-bigquery

I can't figure out the right value to pass into the `--schedule` parameter when using the CLI.

**Example call**

```
bq mk \
--transfer_config \
--project_id=myproject \
--data_source=google_cloud_storage \
--display_name=acs_sites --target_dataset=mydataset \
--schedule='???' \
--params='{
  "data_path_template":"gs://mybucket/data/foo/*.csv",
  "destination_table_name_template":"blah",
  "file_format":"CSV",
  "skip_leading_rows":"1",
  "field_delimiter":",",
  "quote":"\"",
  "write_disposition":"APPEND",
  "max_bad_records":"0"
}'
```

**Notes**

- With `--schedule` excluded, BigQuery defaults the transfer to 24 hours
- `--schedule='every 6 hours'` works as expected
- `--schedule=None` doesn't work
- `--schedule='None'` doesn't work
- `--schedule=''` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derp, `--schedule=None` *does* work. I had an unrelated error that made me think otherwise.